# Installing node with nvm fails?

Tags: node.js, nvm

I am on a mac and I installed nvm using curl, worked fine. I 'nvm install node', I get:

```
Downloading and installing node v7.10.0...
Downloading https://nodejs.org/dist/v7.10.0/node-v7.10.0-darwin-x64.tar.xz...
######################################################################## 100.0%
Computing checksum with shasum -a 256
Checksums matched!
Error: EISDIR: illegal operation on a directory, read
TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined
    at writeLogFile (/myhomedir/.nvm/versions/node/v7.10.0/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/utils/error-handler.js:205:32)

nvm is not compatible with the npm config "prefix" option: currently set to ""
Run `nvm use --delete-prefix v7.10.0` to unset it.
```

I tried running the '`nvm use --delete-prefix v7.10.0` command, but it appears to have no effect..

What is going on?

Comment: did you try to delete this npm prefix variable from `~/.npmrc` file.

Comment: That was it, please post as answer and I will mark it as correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Deleting this npm `prefix` variable from `~/.npmrc` should help.